# Visual Studio Code launch.json file for JUnit?

Tags: visual-studio-code, junit4

Can someone point me toward a sample launch.json file for JUnit 4 so I can run tests from Visual Studio Code? I am unable to find an example of this online and all attempts to create one have failed.

I am able to run tests manually from the command line. (FWIW, I'm using CentOS.) Here's what I do to run them:

```
cd /opt/ABBYY/FREngine12/Samples/Java/Hello_VSC/src/test/java
java -cp .:/opt/junit/junit-4.12.jar:/opt/junit/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore Hello.AppTest
```

My Java project is set up to support Maven (I'm not really using Maven -- I've only set it up with Maven because Java debugging in Visual Studio Code will not work without it). So in the .classpath file I've added the following entries, which should add the .jar files from my command line call to the code path:

```
 <classpathentry kind="lib" path="/opt/junit/junit-4.12.jar" />
 <classpathentry kind="lib" path="/opt/junit/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar" />
```

When I try to set up the launch.json file, I'm attempting to do something like this:

```
    {
        "type": "java",
        "name": "Test-<Hello_VSC>",
        "request": "launch",
        "cwd": "/opt/ABBYY/FREngine12/Samples/Java/Hello_VSC/src/test/java/",
        "console": "internalConsole",
        "stopOnEntry": false,
        "mainClass": "Hello.AppTest",
        "projectName": "Hello_VSC",
        "args": "org.junit.runner.JUnitCore Hello.AppTest",
    },
```

However, I get this error message:

```
Error: Main method not found in class Hello.AppTest, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)
or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application
```

Even if I change cwd to a completely bogus directory, I get the same error message. I don't know if my type parameter is wrong, my cwd parameter is wrong, or if it's something else.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

Never mind -- I figured it out. I guess I had everything set up correctly with my project, but didn't realize that the proper way to run tests with the Java extensions for Visual Studio Code was to simply click on the Explorer (file) icon, then expand the "Test Explorer" option, explore down to whatever test(s) you want to run, right-click, and then choose your testing options. There is no need to use the launch.json file to do this.

Comment: That is one way to do it, yes. +1. Probably easier than my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you search for `tasks.json` (instead of `launch.json`), you will get [this example](https://gist.github.com/felixfbecker/1b03770e83bf795ebde8)

```
/*
    Example for quick Java compilation and unit tests in VS Code.
    Works well with simple BlueJ projects.
    Hit Ctrl+Shift+B to compile currently open file with javac.
    Hit Ctrl+Shift+T to test currently open test class.
    See red wiggles for compilation errors / failed assertions or click exclamation mark in the status bar.
    Uses a few workarounds for individual commands per task and filename without extension.
    This is written for Windows but it should be easy to adopt for Linux and Mac.
*/
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "suppressTaskName": true,
    "showOutput": "silent",
    "windows": {
        "command": "powershell",
        "args": ["-Command"],
        "tasks": [
            {
                // tests the currently open test class. java has to be in %PATH% and the jUnit-jar in %CLASSPATH%.
                "taskName": "junit",
                "args": ["$env:CLASSPATH += ';${fileDirname}'; $class = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension('${fileBasename}'); java org.junit.runner.JUnitCore $class | Select-String -NotMatch -Pattern 'at (?!.+${fileBasename})'"],
                "isTestCommand": true,
                "problemMatcher": {
                    "owner": "java",
                    "fileLocation": ["relative", "${fileDirname}"],
                    "pattern": [
                        {
                            "regexp": "^(.*)$",
                            "message": 1
                        },
                        {
                            "regexp": "^\\s*at .+\\((.+):([0-9]+)\\)$",
                            "file": 1,
                            "line": 2
                        }
                    ]
                }
           },
       ]
    }
}
```

But it is in "0.1.0", so you will have to [convert it to 2.0.0](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_convert-from-010-to-200) first.