# Where to set vmArgs for JUnit in VS Code?

Tags: java, unit-testing, visual-studio-code, junit

I have a Java project with numerous unit tests. In Visual Studio Code, I can run all the tests from the “Testing” tab. Several fail, however, because I need to provide some required VM arguments for them to run properly. We use Maven as our build system.

I know the syntax to provide VM args, but I can’t find the launch configurations for the JUnit tests. I just auto-generated a `launch.json`, but it doesn’t have a Junit configuration. Yet, VS Code clearly knows how to launch the unit tests, because when I tell it to do it (from the Testing pane), it runs them (even the ones that error-out).

This answer ([Visual Studio Code launch.json file for JUnit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50865309/visual-studio-code-launch-json-file-for-junit)) indicates I can just right-click on the unit test to provide options, but all I get are:

- Run Test
- Debug Test
- Go to Test
- Hide Test

The auto-generated launch.json is pretty basic. The two configurations it generated are kind of useless, because it’s a library, not an executable program.

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "java",
            "name": "Launch Current File",
            "request": "launch",
            "mainClass": "${file}"
        },
        {
            "type": "java",
            "name": "Launch RunObject",
            "request": "launch",
            "mainClass": "com.ourcompany.RunObject",
            "projectName": "OurCommon"
        }
    ]
}
```

Where do I set the VM args for unit tests?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### For Java Tests

(Run from the editor,) We can use "java.test.config"!
With this `settings.json`:

```json
{
    "java.test.config": {
        "vmArgs": ["-Dfoo=bar", "-Dbar=baz"]
    },
 ...
```

This test succeeds:

```java
    @Test
    public void testFoo() {
        assertEquals("bar", System.getProperty("foo"));
        assertEquals("baz", System.getProperty("bar"));
    }
```

(run from editor).

See here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-testing

..and completely different to:

---

#### launch.json

Where it is (also):

```json
...,
"vmArgs": "-Dfoo=bar"
...
```

..but something totally different in vs code infrastructure.

See:

- https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-debugging
- https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_launch-configurations
- https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-debugging#_configuration-options

See also:

---

#### tasks.json

(For "build tasks" (which can also be tests)) :
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks.

Comment: Thank you, but I already know how to add vmArgs. I just can't find the JUnit launch configuration to add them to.

Comment: Welcome, but your question suggests, that you *don't*!